# There is one service having many db conversation in one session. Getting lock mode on table when inserting rows in db

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
try {
    session.save(table1);
    session.save(table2);
    session.findBy("from table2 where some conditions"); 
    for(List list : list1ofTransientObjectPassFromUI){ 
     session.save(table3); 
    }  
    session.save(table4);
   // saving data in multiple tables. 
   tx.commit(); 
}catch(Exception e){ 
   tx.rollback(); 
}
```

(1) There are also indexes on above tables to make select statement faster.
(2) 6 to 7 tables are being saved.

Comment: Hi there! Could you please add code snippets about what you tried?

Comment: Hi I edited my question, it is sample code. There are indexes on each table, saving multiple rows in few tables. Also near about 202340 rows in one table which is being used to insert data.